# Inclusão eixo X nome dos meses

Tags: r, ggplot2

Não estou conseguindo mudar/incluir no eixo x a informação de meses no formato nominal.
Dados:

```
dt;AverageTemperature;Month;Year;media_tempMes;
1846-01-01;26.499;1;1846;25.5466;
1846-02-01;25.725;2;1846;25.7102;
1846-03-01;26.503;3;1846;25.8288;
1846-04-01;25.030;4;1846;25.8480;
1846-05-01;25.731;5;1846;26.2432;
1846-06-01;25.835;6;1846;25.9302;
1846-07-01;26.162;7;1846;26.0542;
1846-08-01;27.149;8;1846;27.4178;
1846-09-01;27.184;9;1846;28.4260;
1846-10-01;26.003;10;1846;27.2222;
1846-11-01;25.310;11;1846;26.0274;
1846-12-01;25.823;12;1846;26.2276;
1896-01-01;25.073;1;1896;25.5466;
1896-02-01;25.343;2;1896;25.7102;
1896-03-01;24.865;3;1896;25.8288;
1896-04-01;25.036;4;1896;25.8480;
1896-05-01;25.227;5;1896;26.2432;
1896-06-01;24.981;6;1896;25.9302;
1896-07-01;25.194;7;1896;26.0542;
1896-08-01;26.822;8;1896;27.4178;
1896-09-01;27.836;9;1896;28.4260;
1896-10-01;26.822;10;1896;27.2222;
1896-11-01;25.902;11;1896;26.0274;
1896-12-01;25.981;12;1896;26.2276;
1946-01-01;25.170;1;1946;25.5466;
1946-02-01;25.654;2;1946;25.7102;
1946-03-01;25.773;3;1946;25.8288;
1946-04-01;26.004;4;1946;25.8480;
1946-05-01;26.510;5;1946;26.2432;
1946-06-01;26.140;6;1946;25.9302;
1946-07-01;25.961;7;1946;26.0542;
1946-08-01;27.368;8;1946;27.4178;
1946-09-01;28.105;9;1946;28.4260;
1946-10-01;27.432;10;1946;27.2222;
1946-11-01;26.027;11;1946;26.0274;
1946-12-01;25.471;12;1946;26.2276;
1996-01-01;26.105;1;1996;25.5466;
1996-02-01;26.456;2;1996;25.7102;
1996-03-01;25.891;3;1996;25.8288;
1996-04-01;26.089;4;1996;25.8480;
1996-05-01;26.471;5;1996;26.2432;
1996-06-01;25.823;6;1996;25.9302;
1996-07-01;26.125;7;1996;26.0542;
1996-08-01;28.366;8;1996;27.4178;
1996-09-01;29.445;9;1996;28.4260;
1996-10-01;27.034;10;1996;27.2222;
1996-11-01;26.286;11;1996;26.0274;
1996-12-01;26.891;12;1996;26.2276;
2012-01-01;24.886;1;2012;25.5466;
2012-02-01;25.373;2;2012;25.7102;
2012-03-01;26.112;3;2012;25.8288;
2012-04-01;27.081;4;2012;25.8480;
2012-05-01;27.277;5;2012;26.2432;
2012-06-01;26.872;6;2012;25.9302;
2012-07-01;26.829;7;2012;26.0542;
2012-08-01;27.384;8;2012;27.4178;
2012-09-01;29.560;9;2012;28.4260;
2012-10-01;28.820;10;2012;27.2222;
2012-11-01;26.612;11;2012;26.0274;
2012-12-01;26.972;12;2012;26.2276;
```

construindo o plot:

```
p_plm <- ggplot(palmas, aes(x = Month, y = AverageTemperature, color = as.factor(Year))) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  theme_light(base_size = 20) +
  xlab("Mês")+
  ylab("Temperatura Média") +
  #scale_x_discrete(labels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"))+
  scale_color_discrete("") +
  ggtitle("Temperatura ao longo dos anos") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18))
p_plm
```

Obtenho esse resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tirando o # do scale_x_discrete, não consigo plotar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A classe do atributo "Month" está como inteiro e do atributo "dt" como POSIXct.

Alguma dica de como conseguir colocar o nome dos meses?

Comment: Bem vindo(a) à plataforma. E, desde já, sujiro a leitura dos seguintes artigos: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1). Ambos artigos, vos ensinará como elaborar uma boa pergunta, evitando com isso, votos negativos e, até mesmo, de fechamento. Boa sorte! Aproveite todo nosso potencial e volte sempre!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, confirme se todos os pacotes abaixo estão instalados na sua máquina:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(stringr)
library(scales)
```

Em seguida, vamos enganar o R. Eu vou pegar a coluna `dt`, que possui as datas completas, e colocá-las todas no ano de 2012. Assim, todos os meses ficarão sobrepostos no gráfico. Em seguida, vou usar a função `ymd` (year, month, day) para converter essa coluna para um formato de data.

```
palmas <- palmas %>%
  mutate(dt = str_replace(dt, "^\\d{4}", "2012")) %>%
  mutate(dt = ymd(dt))
```

E é isso. A partir daí, o gráfico se constrói sozinho:

```
ggplot(palmas, aes(x = dt, y = AverageTemperature, color = as.factor(Year))) +
  geom_line(size = 2) +
  theme_light(base_size = 20) +
  xlab("Mês")+
  ylab("Temperatura Média") +
  scale_color_discrete("") +
  ggtitle("Temperatura ao longo dos anos") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", labels = date_format("%b"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso os meses em seu computador não estejam em português, rode o comando abaixo para que sua instalação do `R` fique configurada nesse idioma.

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "pt_BR")
#> [1] "pt_BR/pt_BR/pt_BR/C/pt_BR/en_US.UTF-8"
```